# D3.js JSON forEach map to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I have this JSON file which I'm trying to use in my current D3.js project. You can see from the file excerpt that it contains several information. I scraped it from [this site](http://www.vdc-sy.info/index.php/en/martyrs/1/c29ydGJ5PWEua2lsbGVkX2RhdGV8c29ydGRpcj1ERVNDfGFwcHJvdmVkPXZpc2libGV8ZXh0cmFkaXNwbGF5PTB8) (if you are interested in the context)

```
  [{
    "rowid":1,
    "Name":"Hasan Ali Saad al-Hareeri ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Daraa",
    "Area":"Sawara",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":2,
    "Name":"Riham Adnan Swais ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Female",
    "Province":"Homs",
    "Area":"Telbeiseh",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":3,
    "Name":"Ammar Ahmad al-Njoam ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Aleppo",
    "Area":"Jarablus",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Explosion"
  },
  {
    "rowid":4,
    "Name":"Yaseen Slaiman al-Salkhadi ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Daraa",
    "Area":"Jassim",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":5,
    "Name":"Ayman Noman Qanatra ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Daraa",
    "Area":"Jassim",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":6,
    "Name":"Abdul Kareem Mohammad al-Tamki ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Daraa",
    "Area":"Sheikh Miskeen",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":7,
    "Name":"Ahmad Mohammad al-Tamki ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Child - Male",
    "Province":"Daraa",
    "Area":"Sheikh Miskeen",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":8,
    "Name":"Hamze Mohammad al-Tamki ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Daraa",
    "Area":"Sheikh Miskeen",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":9,
    "Name":"Mohammad Ahmad al-Khaleel ",
    "Status":"Non-Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Daraa",
    "Area":"Sheikh Miskeen",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":10,
    "Name":"Abdul Kareem Abdul Lateef al-Mohammad ",
    "Status":"Non-Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Hama",
    "Area":"Lattamna",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shooting"
  },
  {
    "rowid":11,
    "Name":"Mahdi Basem Qatteni ",
    "Status":"Non-Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Khan Sheikhoun",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shooting"
  },
  {
    "rowid":12,
    "Name":"Ahmad Ibraheem al-Sayed Omar ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Aleppo",
    "Area":"",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":13,
    "Name":"Unidentified ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Child - Male",
    "Province":"Aleppo",
    "Area":"Kafrnaya",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":14,
    "Name":"Unidentified 1 ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Female",
    "Province":"Aleppo",
    "Area":"Bazzaa",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":15,
    "Name":"Unidentified 2 ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Child - Male",
    "Province":"Aleppo",
    "Area":"Bazzaa",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":16,
    "Name":"Unidentified 3 ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Child - Male",
    "Province":"Aleppo",
    "Area":"Bazzaa",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":17,
    "Name":"Mohammad Ahmad al-Farhoud ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Telminis",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shooting"
  },
  {
    "rowid":18,
    "Name":"Yousef al-Saleh ",
    "Status":"Non-Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Kafroumeh",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shooting"
  },
  {
    "rowid":19,
    "Name":"Basel Hsain al-Knoah ",
    "Status":"Non-Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Kafroumeh",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shooting"
  },
  {
    "rowid":20,
    "Name":"Basel Abdul Rahman Qintareh ",
    "Status":"Non-Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Kafroumeh",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shooting"
  },
  {
    "rowid":21,
    "Name":"Hani Khairallah Jbaneej ",
    "Status":"Non-Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Kafroumeh",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shooting"
  },
  {
    "rowid":22,
    "Name":"Ahmad Mohammad al-Shartah ",
    "Status":"Non-Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Kafroumeh",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shooting"
  },
  {
    "rowid":23,
    "Name":"wife of Faisal al-Ahmad al-Khaleefe ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Female",
    "Province":"Deir Ezzor",
    "Area":"Qourieh",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":24,
    "Name":"Unidentified ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Deir Ezzor",
    "Area":"Takaya",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Kidnapping - Execution"
  },
  {
    "rowid":25,
    "Name":"Unidentified 1 ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Deir Ezzor",
    "Area":"Tabya Jazera village",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Kidnapping - Execution"
  },
  {
    "rowid":26,
    "Name":"Unidentified 2 ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Deir Ezzor",
    "Area":"Tabya Jazera village",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Kidnapping - Execution"
  },
  {
    "rowid":27,
    "Name":"Unidentified 3 ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Deir Ezzor",
    "Area":"Tabya Jazera village",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Kidnapping - Execution"
  },
  {
    "rowid":28,
    "Name":"Unidentified 4 ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Deir Ezzor",
    "Area":"Tabya Jazera village",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Kidnapping - Execution"
  },
  {
    "rowid":29,
    "Name":"Unidentified 5 ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Deir Ezzor",
    "Area":"Tabya Jazera village",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Kidnapping - Execution"
  },
  {
    "rowid":30,
    "Name":"Fayez Qabaqji ",
    "Status":"Non-Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Lattakia",
    "Area":"Turkmen mount",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-10",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shooting"
  },
  {
    "rowid":31,
    "Name":"Fahed al-Asali ",
    "Status":"Non-Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Male",
    "Province":"Damascus",
    "Area":"Jobar",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-09",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Shooting"
  },
  {
    "rowid":32,
    "Name":"Amoun Murad ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Female",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Jisr Shagour: Mraand",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-09",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":33,
    "Name":"Kafa Mezweq ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Female",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Jisr Shagour: Mraand",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-09",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":34,
    "Name":"Hala Mohammad ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Female",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Jisr Shagour: Mraand",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-09",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":35,
    "Name":"Ahmad Mezweq ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Child - Male",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Jisr Shagour: Mraand",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-09",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":36,
    "Name":"Ahlam Mezweq ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Child - Female",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Jisr Shagour: Mraand",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-09",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":37,
    "Name":"Adnan Hussain Haj Kheder ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Child - Male",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Jisr Shagour: Mraand",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-09",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  },
  {
    "rowid":38,
    "Name":"Wife of Hussain Haj Kheder ",
    "Status":"Civilian",
    "Sex":"Adult - Female",
    "Province":"Idlib",
    "Area":"Jisr Shagour: Mraand",
    "Date_of_Death":"2015-12-09",
    "Cause_of_Death":"Warplane shelling"
  }]
```

I now nested it so i can sort it by date "Date_of_Death", "Cause_of_Death" and "Province" so I get the total number of casualties per incident because right now I have information about every single person. I think this should work for me. Now I am stuck with the problem that I can't get the total amount of incidents per Province each day. I tried to get it over the array length but this did not work out. I am missing something but I can't tell exactly what. Can you help me out to map it into a new array which contains 
information about the date, the cause of death, the amount of people died, and the province it happened in?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Learning D3</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Place all DOM elements here -->
<script>

var martyr;

d3.json("martyrs_2015.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  //martyr = json;
 //console.log(martyr);
 martyr = getGroupedDate(json);
 console.log(martyr);
 martyrrender(martyr);
});


function getGroupedDate(data){
 var groupedDate = d3.nest()
 .key(function(d) { return d.Date_of_Death; })
 .key(function(d) { return d.Cause_of_Death; })
 .key(function(d) { return d.Province })
 .key(function(d) { return d.Area })
 .entries(data);
 return groupedDate;
}


function martyrrender(data){
 console.log(data.length);
 martyr.forEach(function (martyr) {
  var arr = data.map(function(d){
   return{
    key: martyr,
    value: d[martyr].length,
    cause: d.Cause_of_Death,
   }
  });
  console.log(arr);
 });

}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement is

*Now I am stuck with the problem that I can't get the total amount of incidents per Province each day*

To get that first group the data as per the province using:

```
function getGroupedDate(data) {
  //first group the data on the basis of province
  var groupedDate = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.Province;
    })
    .entries(data);
  return groupedDate;
}
```

Next use this grouped data and group it for the date of death like this

```
function martyrrender(martyr) {
  var arr = [];
  martyr.forEach(function(martyr) {
    //grouping the data on basis of Date_of_death
    var groupedDate = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.Date_of_Death;
      })
      .entries(martyr.values);

    groupedDate.forEach(function(gd) {
      //creating the array
      var dta = {
        province: martyr.key,//province data
        date: gd.key,//date of death
        value: gd.values.length//no of deaths happened in the provnce
      }
      arr.push(dta);
    });
  });
  return arr;
}
```

The above function will give array of deaths happened on date per province.

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yPYbYqdp9IR3uCygmKRM?p=preview)

In the code snippet you provided one cannot have multiple keys for grouping, you can have just one key to group.

```
function getGroupedDate(data){
    var groupedDate = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Date_of_Death; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.Cause_of_Death; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.Province })
    .key(function(d) { return d.Area })
    .entries(data);
    return groupedDate;
}
```

Hope this helps!